# try to echo a variable in ubuntu bash script gets null

Tags: linux, terminal, null, echo

I'm trying to understand why the same command

```
echo "$LOGNAME, $PWD, $OSTYPE, $BASH"
```

gets different outputs while typing directly in terminal vs in bash script in the same directory. As the pictures show, the bash script prints OSTYPE and BASH as null.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oITdN.png)

my bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#my second script :)
clear;
while true
do
    echo "\nenter\n1 to login username, pwd, os type and bash type\n2 to date and time and calendar\n3 to pwd and ls\n4 to archiving your home directory\n5 to exit"
    read input;
    case $input in
        "1")echo "$LOGNAME, $PWD, $OSTYPE, $BASH";;
        "2")echo "date and time:$(date -R)\ncal:\n$(cal)";;
        "3")echo "$(pwd)\n$(ls -l)";;
        "4")echo "trying to archive";tar -czf archive.tar.gz *;;
        "5")echo "goodbye";exit 0;;
        "*")echo "try again";clear;;
    esac
done
```

case 1) line outputs : nader,/home/nader/Desktop/del,linux-gnu,/bin/bash
 if entered separately in terminal. and gets nader, /home/nader/Desktop/del, , if executed in script file.

Comment: it works as expected on my environment

Comment: are you running the script with a sudo command? if so, you need to inerith the variables with the -E switch